# A GPS app which rewards exploration?

Tags: gps

I read about an Android/iOS mobile app recently, but didn't note its name. The app works with GPS, and the idea is that you get points for visiting a part of the world which hasn't yet been explored (i.e. logged by a user of the app). Does anyone know what the app is?

Comment: App for what OS? I vaguely remember there was one such app for OSM on Android (see [my list here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_various)), but am not sure which one. Probably StreetComplete, as they have "Quests"…

Comment: It's not StreetComplete, or any other on your list. It was a *news* article. It  had a cool, odd name. I've updated my question with the OS.